# How to implement auto unsubscribing in EventBus when subscriber terminates

Tags: akka

For example I have event bus from documentation:

```
import akka.event.EventBus
import akka.event.LookupClassification

final case class MsgEnvelope(topic: String, payload: Any)

class LookupBusImpl extends EventBus with LookupClassification {
  type Event = MsgEnvelope
  type Classifier = String
  type Subscriber = ActorRef

  override protected def classify(event: Event): Classifier = event.topic

  override protected def publish(event: Event, subscriber: Subscriber): Unit = {
    subscriber ! event.payload
  }

  override protected def compareSubscribers(a: Subscriber, b: Subscriber): Int =
    a.compareTo(b)

  override protected def mapSize: Int = 128

}
```

If my subscriber(Actor) dies, it will not removed from subscribers. It's correct? Should I unsubscribe in `postStop` or maybe other way?

Answer (score 1):

Use `postStop` hook - it's the simplest solution that does the job

```
override def postStop(): Unit = {
  context.system.eventStream.unsubscribe(self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if you can extend `akka.event.ManagedActorClassification` as that already contains an implementation that watches actors and unsubscribes if they terminate. If not possible to extend that trait, you may at least get some ideas of how to do it from that implementation.

Comment: It's not possible to extend it (`Classifier` should be `ActorRef`). Okey i will look inside.But i think the most simplest way for me - have watcher actor, that will manage terminates.